# Bash check if file/directory is readable/accesibble and include hidden files/directories

Tags: shell, posix

can someone please help me what should i do do be able find all files/subdirectories in directory and also files/subdirectories in subdirectories of main directory that are not readable/accessible?

I was trying to do something like:

```
for file in *
do
if [ -f "$file" ] && [ -r "$file" ];then
fi
done
```

But it doesnt work for hidden files. What should i add/change to find also hidden files/directories

Comment: `*` doesn't match hidden files. Use `.* *`.

Comment: And is there any chance of how to include subdirectories of the main directory? Because its searching only in the given directory.